How to rename Flutter Project and move file location without causing bunch of errors
I originally downloaded the Tflite Tensorflow 0.10.4 package and used the live_object_detection flutter example as the template of a flutter project. Now that I am done with the project, I want to rename it and move it from the package to a different folder.
I moved the file and renamed it, but I got problems with saying it failed to read the Android Manifest xml file in App/Main in android. It also had errors since it was attempting to access a file in the Tflite package, even though it is in my pubspec.yaml file. I am very confused on how to do this. I know maybe renaming it may be easy, but this really confused me. I also tried making a new project and importing my lib and pubspec.yaml file
Error parsing LocalFile: 'C:\Flutter\Nova\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and try again. 

What I mean by attempting to access a file in Tflite package
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

It says that "Target of URI doesn't exist." I have the package downloaded (like pubspec.yaml and ran flutter pub get), but since I moved the example from inside the 0.10.4 package to outside of it, it says there is an error. Do I have to slightly modify the Import?
Another issue with my pubspec.yaml dependencies.
Because Nova depends on tflite_flutter from path which doesn't exist (No pubspec.yaml found for package tflite_flutter in C:\.), version solving failed.

Originally I never needed a path since the project was inside of the tflite package. now im not sure on how my path should be like. When I put a path, it says that there isn't a pubspec.yaml in the path.
tflite_flutter:
    path: "C:/Flutter/tflite_flutter-0.10.4/pubspec.yaml"

I'm also getting a lot of issues with imports. My project is now not recognizing any package import. I've changed them to include my new project name, but there are still issues. Says Target of URI doesn't exist. I can't run flutter pub get due to the tflite_flutter path issue.
Please help! Thanks!
